# How can we find the equation of the symmetrical axis of 2 functions?

Tags: functions, symmetry

Let's consider 2 functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defiened :
$f(x)=ax+b$
$g(x)=cx+d$

Let's also consider a function $m(x)$ defiened as $m(x)=ex+h$ that verifie this property :
$f(x)$ is symmetrical to $g(x)$ in relation to $m(x)$. ($m(x)$ is the equation of the of the line which is the axis of symmetry between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$)
[image]

Here $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x) =0.5x$.
Then $m(x)=1x$

My question is how can we find what is the expression of $m(x)$ with the expression of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

I already solved that for $e$ (in the equation $m(x)=ex+h$) :

$e=\text{tan}(\frac{\text{tan}^{-1}(a)+\text{tan}^{-1}(c)}{2})$

But I can't solve it for $h$.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Note that all three lines meet at the same point $(x_i,y_i)$:
$$ax_i+b=cx_i+d\\(a-c)x_i=d-b\\x_i=\frac{d-b}{a-c}$$
Then use $$ax_i+b=ex_i+h\\h=(a-e)x_i+b$$